How to display Tables and Figures in the Appendix with unified labeling (A1, A2, ...) instead of separate numbering for Figures and Tables?
I went to show in my Appendix Tables and Figures as A1, .. , A2. Currently, I am using this in my code to insert the appendix. However, this Figures now as Figure A1, Figure A2 ... and Table A1, Table A2 ... . How can I stop the separation in the Appendix for Figures and Tables ? :
\appendix
\markright{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A.\arabic{figure}} % Redefine figure numbering
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A.\arabic{table}} % Redefine table numbering
\setcounter{table}{0}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\captionsetup{listof=false}
\input{appendix}


Simplest is to use figure for all of them, you don't have to use table just because there is a tabular the only reason to have separate figure and table environments is to have separate counters and to allow them to float past each other

@cfr It's not necessarily wrong, there is nothing wrong with calling all inserts figure, and less confusing than calling some figure and some table but with the same number sequence

@DavidCarlisle Sorry: you're right.

@DavidCarlisle that is right, easiest solution and worked

Despite what @David Carlisle says, I think that there is a third feature of separate figure and table environments: the prefix in the caption, which is also used by tools like cleveref.
One can do the following to force figure and table to use the same counter, but it is quite hacky.
\renewcommand*{\thefigure}{A\arabic{figure}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\c@table}{\c@figure}
\renewcommand*{\thetable}{\thefigure}
\renewcommand*{\ftype@figure}{\ftype@table}
\makeatother

If you want these setting only starting with \appendix, you might want to put this code inside \AddToHook{cmd/appendix/after}{...}, and the whole expression in the preamble.

Following @DavidCarlisle: Simplest is to use figure for all of them, you don't have to use table just because there is a tabular the only reason to have separate figure and table environments is to have separate counters and to allow them to float past each other. Easy and works:
\appendix
\markright{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{figure}} % Redefine figure numbering
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}} % Redefine table numbering
\renewcommand{\figurename}{} % Remove "Abbildung" prefix for figure captions
\renewcommand{\tablename}{} % Remove "Tabelle" prefix for table captions
\setcounter{table}{0}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\captionsetup{listof=false}

\input{appendix}

while setting \begin{figure} ... \end{figure} for all objects in the appendix.
